# Fluid simulation problems

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want to do animation which starts fluid at frame 150. I get that by setting offset to -150. but till then it gives this domain with material of fluid. What should I do to do it correctly??[image]

Comment: you could simply hide it at animation start and reveal it at 150 keyframing its visibility

Comment: I had the same idea.... BUT HOW???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you could simply hide it at animation start and reveal it at 150 keyframing its visibility.

To do this you can keyframe the domain object "eye" icon when it must change state (press the i key on it) in the graph editor you can edit this as usual but it will add a "restrict view" channel.

This can toggle visibility on/off by getting values of 0/1 (visible/invisible) as below:

[image]

which works like this

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help... it worked in 3D view... but it gave same problem in animation video....    this is my file.... please check it....     https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RuKfxHl3q60cItN3YHEBqkRVEDmZOT-J

Comment: Ok I'll.look at that soon, but you can do the same tovtoggle renderability, just add keyframes for the little camera icon, aside the "eye" one...

Comment: ahhaa..... nice idea.. I'll try that...

Comment: its working...!!!

Comment: good! sorry it was my fault, to let it show in the viewport I forgot to mention about the other icon. As you now discovered, it is really the same thing but for renderability instead of viewport visibility...

Comment: no problem.... always good to know more things... it will be useful in future...